# Too Many Requests у бота Nodejs / telegraf js

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, requests, бот

бот периодически выкидывает   Error: 429: Too Many Requests: retry after 16
когда слишком много запросов, подскажите как прописать запуск бота
в документации нашел следующее

```
telegraf.startPolling([timeout], [limit], [allowedUpdates], [stopCallback])
```

также следующие примеры запуска

```
 if (!config.webhook) { 
   const { timeout, limit, allowedUpdates, stopCallback } = config.polling || {} 
   return this.telegram.deleteWebhook() 
     .then(() => this.startPolling(timeout, limit, allowedUpdates, stopCallback)) 
     .then(() => debug('Bot started with long-polling')) 
 } 

to
        if (!config.webhook) {
          const { timeout, limit, allowedUpdates, stopCallback } = config.polling || {}
          return this.telegram.deleteWebhook()
            .then(() => this.startPolling(timeout, limit, allowedUpdates, stopCallback))
            .then(() => {
              debug('Bot started with long-polling')
              return { ok: true, error: null, type: 'long-polling' }
            })
        }
```

вопрос где прописать какие участки, чтобы бот принимал ограниченое количество запросов и не выбивал ошибку Too Many Requests, знаю что у телеграма есть ограничение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Не там ищите

Данная ошибка не зависит:

- от языка программирования
- от используемых библиотек
- от способа запуска

### Что делать?

Начните **контролировать ИСХОДЯЩИЕ запросы** в адрес API Telegram.

Если частота запросов спровоцирована флудом со стороны пользователей (т.е. входящими запросами) - используйте троттлинг (см. leacky bucket).

Если частые запросы создаёте вы сами - добавьте ожидание между запросами.